# R plot window split screen - second order

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to do something like

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1));
```

then draw

```
ts.plot(rnorm(15));
```

I would then like to split row 2 further into a 2-cross-3 matrix with a theoretical sub-call to par() again ...

Comment: For base graphics the function to use is `layout`, but it does require that you start with `layout` and not use `par`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look here for a nice explanation for layout, par etc. :  http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~jkim/Rfigurelayout.pdf

**Your layout**

```
m <- matrix(c(1,1,1,
              2,3,4,
              5,6,7), ncol=3, by=T)
l <- layout(m)
layout.show(l)  # show layout to doublecheck

# layout cells are filled in the order of the numbers
# set par, e.g. mar each time if required

for (i in 1:7) {
  par(mar=c(i,i,i,i))
  hist(rnorm(100), col=i)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(1618)
multiplot(height = 8, width = 6, rows = 5, cols = 3, matrix = c(1,1,1, 1,1,1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
for (i in 11:20) {
  plot(rcauchy(i), pch = 19, col = i)
}
dev.copy2pdf(file = "./tmp.pdf")
```

[image]

```
multiplot <- function(width = 8.5, height = 11, rows, cols, matrix = c(1, 1)) {
    x11(width, height)
    layout(matrix(c(matrix), rows, cols, byrow = TRUE))
}
```